# CSS set width to the end of the page in CSS Flex Div

Tags: html, css

I would like set width of 3rd column of  to maximum width to the end of the page. However, I cannot set to width: 100%. If I set width: 100%, if too long word will go to the next line. I don't want put into next line for long sentence.

[image]

May I know how can I set the width of third  above to the end of the page if sentence is too long and not go to the next line at all.

Here is my css code

```
.harbor {
    min-width: 7.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here is my html code

```
 <div class="gangway-header-container">
    <div>
      <h1 class="gangway-header-text" data-bind="text: gateLocation, attr: { 'title': gateLocation}">
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="gangway-configurarion-reposition">
        <div class="gangway-configuration-layout oj-flex"> 
          <div class="gate-type-wrapper oj-flex">
            <oj-label id="typeLbl" for="gateType">
              <span  data-bind='text: pageLabels().type'></span> : 
            </oj-label>
            <oj-label
              class="gate-type-label" 
                id="gateType"> 
                <span>
                  <oj-bind-text value="{{gateTypeLabel}}"></oj-bind-text>
                </span>
            </oj-label>
          </div>
          <div class="traffic-direction-wrapper oj-flex">
            <oj-label id="directionLbl" for="trafficDirection" >
              <span  data-bind='text: pageLabels().direction'></span> :
            </oj-label>
        
            <oj-select-one
              id="trafficDirection"
              class="traffic-direction-selection"
              options="[[trafficDirectionArray]]"
              value="{{selectedTrafficDirection}}"
              on-value-changed="[[trafficDirectionChanged.bind($data)]]">
            </oj-select-one>
          </div>
          <!-- Add new Harbor display here -->
          <div class="harbor oj-flex">
            <oj-label id="harborLbl" for="harborType">
              <span  data-bind='text: pageLabels().harbor'></span> : 
            </oj-label>
            <oj-label class="harbor-type-label" :title="[[gateTypeLabel]]" id="harborType"> 
                <span>
                  <oj-bind-text value="{{harborLabel}}"></oj-bind-text>
                </span>
            </oj-label>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post relevant HTML/CSS code

Comment: @Nitheesh I have post my css code

Comment: Hot just CSS, make a working fiddle with html and css so that others can have a look into the real issue

Comment: I added my html code above also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using flexbox, you can set a property of "flex-wrap" to "nowrap" so that the children elements do not "*go to the next line*":

```
.parent-flex-container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap
}
```

Comment: It solved my issues